# Deploy Angular 6 application on Apache 2

Tags: angular, apache2

I have a `Angular 6` application which I need to deploy on `Apache2`. 
I have the code in `/var/www/html/project` folder. Have run `ng build --prod` command and it created a folder called `dist/project` under `/var/www/html/project`

Created the virtual host under `/etc/apache2/sites-available` and enabled the site and `apache2` reloaded.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName testsite.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/project/dist/project/

    <Directory /var/www/html/project/dist/project/>
            Options -MultiViews
            RewriteEngine on

            # Don't rewrite files or directories
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
            RewriteRule ^ - [L]

            # Rewrite everything else to index.html
            # to allow html5 state links
            RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

If I visit `testsite.com`, it is showing blank page.

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Project</title>
<base href="http://testsite.com">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:300,700" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.8e98a03e860d2ebfdf70.css"
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="runtime.a66f828dca56eeb90e02.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.2f4a59095805af02bd79.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.430ebc5e8a6533f9924f.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post the htaccess file

Comment: Check if the base tag of the index.html is pointing correctly to `theDirectory /var/www/html/project/dist/project/` path

Answer (score 0):

can you please check if the '/var/www/html/project/dist/project/' is correct and containing index.html or not?

Also check the permission of this folder

Comment: index.html  is there in the dist folder